# Function Approximation With Scikit-Learn MLP Regressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to approximate a function with two independent variables and one dependent variable. I am using a neural network. For some reason, my approximation with one neuron in the hidden layer is discontinuous, which is impossible for the continuous logistic activation function I am using. How can I fix this? The function is in green, the approximation in red

[image]

I had code months ago that gave me an output I would expect.

[image]

I think it may have something to do with how I am passing in my inputs/output. I checked the input shape, it is (n samples, n features) as fit/predict methods ask for [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html).

Here's how I get my data

```
######################################## Collect dataset
n_input = 2; start = -1; stop = 1; steps = 0.01
x = mesh(n_input, start, stop, steps)
f = decaying_nd(x)
```

where mesh and decaying_nd are defined as

```
# @brief decaying_nd: produces n-dimensional exponentially decaying dataset
# @param x: nested list
# @returns: nested list. Same as mgrid, so for example 1D would look like [[1,2,3]]
def decaying_nd(x):
    n = x.shape[0]
    f = np.ones(x[0].shape)
    for point,_ in np.ndenumerate(f):
        for dim in range(n):
            f[point] *= np.exp(-x[dim][point]**2)
    return f

# @brief mesh: n-dimensional mgrid
# @param n: int
# @param start: float
# @param stop: float
# @param steps: float
# @returns: nested list
def mesh(n, start=-1, stop=1, steps=0.1):
    if n < 1 or not isinstance(n, int):
        raise ValueError('dimension passed to mesh is invalid')
    mgrid = np.mgrid[tuple(slice(start, stop+steps, steps) for _ in range(n))]
    return mgrid
```

```
######################################## Build model
n = 1

regression = MLPRegressor(
hidden_layer_sizes=(n,),
activation='logistic',
solver='lbfgs',
alpha=0,
max_iter=3000,
tol=1e-5,
n_iter_no_change=1000,
random_state=seed
)

######################################## Run model
X = x.reshape(-1, x.shape[0])
F = f.reshape(-1)
regression.fit(X, F)
```

Lastly, here is how I plot

```
# 3D prediction plot

y = regression.predict(X)
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(x[0], x[1], f.reshape(-1), c=f.reshape(-1), cmap='Greens')
ax.scatter3D(x[0], x[1], y.reshape(-1), c=y.reshape(-1), cmap='Reds', marker='x')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. X should have been set like so:

```
X = [[x[0].reshape(-1)[i], x[1].reshape(-1)[i]] for i in range(len(x[0].reshape(-1)))]
```